# Sending variables from Wordpress Contact Form 7 submission to success page

Tags: javascript, wordpress, contact-form-7

I am using Contact Form 7 with Wordpress 3.5.

Currently, when a user submits the message, they are redirected to a success page by using the following in the "Additional Settings" field:

```
on_sent_ok: 'location.replace("http://www.example.org/success-page");'
```

I want to be able to customise the output of the success-page by using the input from a field, for example:

```
on_sent_ok: 'location.replace("http://www.example.org/success-page?name=yourname");'
```

I hoped that by dropping the usual Contact Form 7 shortcodes into the Additional settings, it may have sent the field value with it, but that's not the case.

Can anyone suggest how I can get the field values from contact form 7 into the url, or alternatively send as a $_POST parameter?  It may require some javascript to do this, I guess.

Comment: It seems Wordpress doesn't like URLs with encoded query strings, so these probably need to go as $_POST vars

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is possible but you need the save the posted data from the contact form to the session and show it there.

Add this to your functions.php

```
add_action('wpcf7_mail_sent', 'save_cf7_data');


function save_cf7_data($cf) 
{

    if(session_id() == '') {
       session_start();
    }

    $current_submission = WPCF7_Submission::get_instance();

    $_SESSION['cf7_submission'] = $current_submission->get_posted_data();


}
```

And your success page you just need to print the session var, like:

```
echo $_SESSION['cf7_submission']['name'];
```

That's all.

Comment: i am trying your solution but it doesn't work for me (latest WP & CF7). I get the error message: Notice: Undefined variable: _SESSION
and i have on_sent_ok: "location = 'form-page/thank-you/';"

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use jQuery or Javascript and catch the form on submit.
After the form is caught you can serialize the params and pass them to a custom page to catch them and do things with them.

Example for jQuery:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('.wpcf7-form').each(function () {
        $(this).on('submit', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',    // Can also choose GET instead
                url: 'forms/getParams',
                data: $(this).serialize(),
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    $(this)[0].reset();    // Optional in case you want to clear the form on success
                },
                error: function (data, errorThrown) {
                    console.log(errorThrown);
                }
            });

        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

the 'additional settings' code is javascript and thus is running in the context of the browser. this means you can easily access the form data using normal javascript code

e.g. `on_sent_ok: 'location.replace("http://www.example.org/success-page?name=" + jQuery("input[name=name]").val());'`

Comment: Hi @danielcavanagh - Not sure how to use the "name=name" section of your answer, e.g., if my form field looks like this:

`[dynamichidden form-session-id "form_session_id" id:fid]`

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

i think you should use $_REQUEST['name']; for fetching your post variable on success page.